# Overlay Image orientation changed after saving Image from drawable

Tags: android, image

I am new to Android and working on a project where i have to capture image using custom camera with an overlay image.

I can capture the image with the overlay(combined image) but the problem is the overlay image orientation changes after saving the new combined image,i.e,the overlay image is primarily set in portrait mode but after saving it shows in landscape mode.

I have searched a lot for **How to change the orientation of Drawable Image** but everywhere orientation change is for bitmap image.If i change drawable image into bitmap and change rotation it does not show any overlay image.i didn't know what's wrong with the code.
My code is as follows.

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera camera) {
Bitmap cameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length);
        int   wid = cameraBitmap.getWidth();
        int  hgt = cameraBitmap.getHeight();
        Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(wid,hgt,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newImage);
        canvas.drawBitmap(cameraBitmap, 0f, 0f, null);
      // Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.frame);
       // drawable.setBounds(0,0,drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()*1/2, drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()*1/2);
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.frame);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(270);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 100, 200, true);
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
       Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), rotatedBitmap);
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Photo/");
        storagePath.mkdirs();
        File myImage = new File(storagePath,Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
        try
        { 
          FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myImage);
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(cameraBitmap.toString());
            Log.d("EXIF value", exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION));
            if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("6")) {
                newImage = rotate(newImage, 90);
            } else if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("8")) {
                newImage = rotate(newImage, 270);
            } else if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
                newImage = rotate(newImage, 180);
            } else if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                newImage = rotate(newImage, 90);}
            newImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            camera.startPreview();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + myImage.getAbsolutePath()), "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
            newImage.recycle();
            newImage = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.d("In Saving File", e + "");
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.d("In Saving File", e + "");
        }
    }};

      public Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bitmap, int degree) {
    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();
    Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
    //       mtx.postRotate(degree);
    mtx.setRotate(degree);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
}`
```

Here are the layouts call in mainactivity for camera imageView and overlay image:

`surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.cameraView);//for camera view
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());//for overlay view inflated over the surfaceView
      View view = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay, null);
        view.setSaveEnabled(true);
        LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        this.addContentView(view, layoutParamsControl);`
 
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research on this topic i found that it is not possible to rotate(without Animation) or change image orientation of image from drawable.
I go through the documentation [Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html)  & [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDrawingCacheEnabled(boolean)).
The View documentation states that:

> void setDrawingCacheEnabled(boolean enabled)
>   Enables or disables the drawing cache. When the drawing cache is enabled, the next call to getDrawingCache() or buildDrawingCache() will draw the view in a bitmap. Calling draw(android.graphics.Canvas) will not draw from the cache when the cache is enabled.

After that i add following lines in order to access the image from drawable in the same orientation as original by using **setDrawaingCacheEnabled()** in onPictureTaken() method.

```
 view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap viewCapture = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

In addition to this for setting drawable image dimensions in output screen it is necessary to use setBounds method (which i ignored in my question)

`drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 1/2, drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() * 1/2);`